# EF Core one-to-many infinite includes

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, ef-fluent-api

I have two tables Appointment and TaskAllocation having one to many relationship. now when i get the Appointment

```
public IEnumerable<Appointment> GetAppointments(int employeeId, DateTime date)
    {
        return _context.Appointment.Where(a => a.EmployeeId == employeeId && 
            a.AppointmentDate == date)
           .Include(a=>a.Tasks).ToList();
    }
```

It causes including one appointment with many tasks and again one task with that appointment with many tasks and so on.

Comment: I had the same issue and from looking at the output I noticed there were no calls to load the data after the initial call to get the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your ConfigureService, you need to Add Json Options for handling reference loop handling

```
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
    options.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
});
```

or you may choose to directly ignore reference loops by

```
options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```